# Удалить всё кроме определённых слов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, замена

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить составить регулярное выражение (*литературу читал, на этом моменте не получается*), чтобы, к примеру, из строк

- `ГОСТ Р ИСО/МЭК 27002-2012 Информационная технология. Методы и средства обеспечения безопасности`
- `ГОСТ 2.317-2011 Единая система конструкторской документации. Аксонометрические проекции`
- `Письмо 13218-НТ/10 О разъяснении статуса сводов правил - актуализированных СНиП`
- `СНиП III-40-78 Автомобильные дороги`

удалить всё кроме слов "ГОСТ Р", "ГОСТ", "Письмо" и "СНиП", но только если они в начале строки?

Comment: Как составить? Почитать литературу про регулярные выражения в php и попробовать составить его. Вы, как я понял, не знакомы с регулярными выражениями, так?

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный и полезный ответ. Спеицально для вас дополнил вопрос. Благодарю за  то, что не отправили сервак на апач поднимать, т.к. по вашей логике надо с этого начинать.

Comment: @Pablo просто вопрос так сформулирован, будто Вы вообще не знаете, как работают регулярные выражения. Вы бы привели пример, какую регулярку пытались использовать и какие функции...

Comment: @Pablo и минус не я ставил.

Comment: @ Andrei Khotko в любом случае спасибо за внимание. Может и правдв не понятно что-то описал...

Comment: @0xdb Кончено всё культурно. Только по моему ответ на вопрос (пусть даже в коментах) "Как составить? Почитать литературу..." равнозначен надписи на заглавной странице вашего сайта "Мы закрыты, идите в библиотеку."

Comment: @Pablo Да, посылать почитать или погуглить считается недопустимоым. Кто это делает регулярно, получает сообшение от модераторов. Задавать вопрос, не предлагая собственной попытки решения, тоже не приветствуется. Отвечать на такие вопросы сложно, потому, что не всегда понятен смысл вопроса и уровень познаний автора.

Comment: @0xdb я понял. спасибо. буду стараться в вопросах указывать попытки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^(ГОСТ Р|ГОСТ|Письмо|СНиП)/', 'СНиП III-40-78 Автомобильные дороги', $matches);

if ($matches)
    echo $matches[0];
```

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) - про preg_match описание

`^` - значит: искать с начала.

`|` - означает: или. Т.е. искать ГОСТ Р `ИЛИ` ГОСТ `ИЛИ` Письмо `ИЛИ` СНиП

Comment: Спасибо! то, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Заменить `^(ГОСТ Р|ГОСТ|Письмо|СНиП).*$` на пустую строку.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Пот такая конструкция работает:
preg_replace ("/[^(ГОСТ Р|ГОСТ|Письмо|СНиП)].*$/", "", $queryDoc, -1);

Comment: @Pablo, что-то не то...

Comment: Действительно, что-то не то...